# Python not finding search terms in strings parsed by BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

In Python 3, when I want to return only strings with the term I am interested in, I can do this:

```
phrases = ["1. The cat was sleeping",
        "2. The dog jumped over the cat",
        "3. The cat was startled"]

for phrase in phrases:
    if "dog" in phrase:
        print(phrase)
```

Which of course prints "2. The dog jumped over the cat"

Now what I'm trying to do is make the same concept work with parsed strings in BeautifulSoup. Craigslist, for example, has lots of A Tags, but only the A Tags that also have "hdrlnk" in them are of interest to us. So I:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = "https://chicago.craigslist.org/search/apa"
r = requests.get(url)

soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, "html.parser") 
links = soup.find_all("a")

for link in links:
    if "hdrlnk" in link:
        print(link)
```

Problem is, instead of printing all the A Tags with "hdrlnk" inside, Python prints nothing. And I'm not sure what's going wrong.

Comment: I visited the link, but was unable to find any link with text containing "hdrlink".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

"hdrlnk" is a class attribute on the links. As you say you are only interested in these links just find the links based on class like this:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = "https://chicago.craigslist.org/search/apa"
r = requests.get(url)

soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, "html.parser")
links = soup.find_all("a", {"class": "hdrlnk"})

for link in links:
    print(link)
```

Outputs:

```
<a class="result-title hdrlnk" data-id="6293679332" href="/chc/apa/d/high-rise-2-bedroom-heated/6293679332.html">High-Rise 2 Bedroom Heated Pool Indoor Parking Fire Pit Pet Friendly!</a>
<a class="result-title hdrlnk" data-id="6285069993" href="/chc/apa/d/new-beautiful-studio-in/6285069993.html">NEW-Beautiful Studio in Uptown/free heat</a>
<a class="result-title hdrlnk" data-id="6293694090" href="/chc/apa/d/albany-park-2-bed-1-bath/6293694090.html">Albany Park 2 Bed 1 Bath Dishwasher W/D &amp; Heat + Parking Incl Pets ok</a>
<a class="result-title hdrlnk" data-id="6282289498" href="/chc/apa/d/north-center-2-bed-1-bath/6282289498.html">NORTH CENTER: 2 BED 1 BATH HDWD AC UNITS PROVIDE W/D ON SITE PRK INCLU</a>
<a class="result-title hdrlnk" data-id="6266583119" href="/chc/apa/d/beautiful-2bed-1bath-in-the/6266583119.html">Beautiful 2bed/1bath in the heart of Wrigleyville</a>
<a class="result-title hdrlnk" data-id="6286352598" href="/chc/apa/d/newly-rehabbed-2-bedroom-unit/6286352598.html">Newly Rehabbed 2 Bedroom Unit! Section 8 OK! Pets OK! (NHQ)</a>
```

To get the link href or text use:

```
print(link["href"])
print(link.text)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
for link in links:
    if "hdrlnk" in link["href"]:
        print(link)
```

Answer (score 0):

Just search term in link content, otherwise your code seems fine

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = "https://chicago.craigslist.org/search/apa"
r = requests.get(url)

soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, "html.parser") 
links = soup.find_all("a")

for link in links:
    if "hdrlnk" in link.contents[0]:
        print(link)
```

Or, if you want to search inside href or title, use `link['href']` and `link['title']`

Answer (score 0):

To get the required links, you can use selectors within your script to make the scraper robust and concise.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

base_link = "https://chicago.craigslist.org"
res = requests.get("https://chicago.craigslist.org/search/apa").text
soup = BeautifulSoup(res, "lxml") 
for link in soup.select(".hdrlnk"):
    print(base_link + link.get("href"))
```